# List to lists of lists in recursive calling

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Here is my code:

```
findY mnozP a = 
    if null(Set.toList $ mnozP)==False
        then (
            if (((null(intersect ( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a))==False) && (null(( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) \\ (a))==False)))
                then (((intersect ( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a)) ++ (( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) \\ (a))) ++ findY ( Set.fromList $ tail $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a))
                else findY ( Set.fromList $ tail $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a)
            )
        else []
findY _ a = []
findY _ _ = []
```

This function checks whether is list `mnozP` empty, if it isn't, it takes first item and checks whether its intersection with list `a` is empty `and` its difference is not empty. In case condition is true, realizes these two operations and call it recursively again for the tail of list `b`.
I actually got 2 questions:

1. Let's assume following lists: `a = ["3","4"]` and `mnozP = [["1","6"],["2","4","3","5"]]`. The output is `["3","4","2","5"]`. *Is there any function which can split this list into list of lists according to every single iterations?* Expected output should look like `[["3","4"],["2","5"]]`.
2. While compiling GHCi says following:

   ```
   Warning:
   Pattern match(es) are overlapped
   In an equation for `findY':
       findY _ a = ...
       findY _ _ = ...
   ```

   I'm not sure what's wrong with my patterns. I try to cover all the possible cases which can happen. *Any ideas whats wrong?*

EDIT: *(short summary:)* The function findY should return a list of lists. Every inner list is related to one concrete iteration of recursion (in case conditions is true).

Comment: I think you make code way to complex here. You probably better use `where` clauses, guards, etc. to make the synax cleaner in the first place.

Comment: It is probably also useful to first specify what your function aims to do?

Comment: The compiler furthermore says that the last two lines are actually duplicates, and thus that there is no reason to write both. So you can delete one of the two.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah you're certainly right. Though I'm pretty new into Haskell so i probably don't have the best practises yet. Ad 2, I'm pretty sure I described it well. What's not clear?

Comment: well you write *how* the predicate does something, but it would probably make it easier to spot a problem, given you first specify what the function is aiming to calculate. In words what problem the function should solve.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question to make it clear. By the way I deleted one of the lines you said - no effect. It says warning for the other one I left there.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, you each time want to calculate the difference? Since if the intersection is empty, then you simply never remove elements from the list (so regardless whether there is an element that intersects), you calculate the difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Pseudocode would look like this: `for each set Y in mnozP for which a ∩ Y is nonempty and a \ X is nonempty do:...`. So if the intersection is empty, I do nothing. If the difference is empty, I do nothing too. You can see this condition in code, in my opinion it's pretty obvious.

Comment: And what do you do if both are non-empty?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That is not a subject of this question. Firstly I need to have that list of lists which I get by testing every subset (sublist) of mnozP to the condition. If the condition for actual subset (lets call is `P`) of mnozP match, I realize intersection and difference of `P` and `a`, insert these two created sets (lists) into final list. And this list of lists is my goal.

Comment: So for every element in `mnozP` that satisfies the two conditions, you want two elements in the output?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I guess that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is the list constructor. In your inductive case, you have

```
(((intersect ( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a)) ++ (( Set.toList $ head $ Set.toList $ mnozP) \\ (a))) ++ findY ( Set.fromList $ tail $ Set.toList $ mnozP) (a))
```

which is just

```
as ++ bs ++ cs
```

where `cs` is the result of the recursive call. If `findY` returns a list of lists, so must the whole expression. By the induction hypothesis, `cs` is a list of lists. In other words, the expression to the left in `exp ++ cs` (i.e. `as ++ bs`) must be a list of lists too. But it's not! `intersect` and `\\` return flat lists, which you concatenate together, getting a new flat list.

To fix that problem you just need to wrap your left expression in a list

```
[as ++ bs] ++ cs
```

or use the list constructor

```
(as ++ bs) : cs
```

---

If there's anything else you could get from this, it is that you could have found that out by yourself had the code been written in a more idiomatic way. I'll try to walk you through how I "unpacked" your code.

First, I added a type signature that matched your description.

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Interestingly, this change alone would have pointed out the expression in the inductive case was not right.

Then, I got rid of the `Set <-> []` conversions. You can either ask for your input to be sets, or just plain lists and make sure there are no duplicates. I went with the latter approach:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY mnozP a = 
if null(mnozP)==False
    then (
        if (((null(intersect (head mnozP) (a))==False) && (null(( head mnozP) \\ (a))==False)))
            then (((intersect ( head mnozP) (a)) ++ (( head mnozP) \\ (a))) ++ findY ( tail mnozP) (a))
            else findY ( tail mnozP) (a)
        )
    else []
findY _ a = []
findY _ _ = []
```

It's already getting clearer. There's loads of `()` you can get rid of too. In Haskell, function application is just the space character. So instead of writing `f(x)`, like you would in many languages, you write `f x` and surround with parentheses only to disambiguate expressions:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY mnozP a = 
if (null mnozP) == False
    then
        if (null (intersect (head mnozP) a) == False) && (null (head mnozP \\ a) == False)
            then (intersect (head mnozP) a) ++ (head mnozP \\ a) ++ findY (tail mnozP) a
            else findY (tail mnozP) a
    else []
findY _ a = []
findY _ _ = []
```

Next, notice the many repetitions of `head` and `tail`. You could bind these to variables with a `let` expression, but there's a better way. Haskell allows you to pattern match on the arguments in order to choose what branch should be evaluated depending on the input. Here, we only need to know if the list has a head and a tail, which happens to be exactly how you pattern match a non-empty list:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY (xs : xss) a = 
    if (null (intersect xs a) == False) && (null (xs \\ a) == False)
        then (intersect xs a) ++ (xs \\ a) ++ findY xss a
        else findY xss a
findY _ _ = []
```

See how doing this allowed me to get rid of the first `if` statement? (I also removed the extra pattern match). There is still some redundancy, let's get rid of it:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY (xs : xss) a =
  let as = intersect xs a
      bs = xs \\ a
  in
    if (null as == False) && (null bs == False)
        then as ++ bs ++ findY xss a
        else findY xss a
findY _ _ = []
```

At that point, the issue stands out.

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY (xs : xss) a =
  let as = intersect xs a
      bs = xs \\ a
  in
    if (null as == False) && (null bs == False)
        then (as ++ bs) : findY xss a
        else findY xss a
findY _ _ = []
```

Now it is a matter of style, but I personally find using pattern matching is more elegant than if statements most of the time. Not so much here though:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY (xs : xss) a =
  let as = intersect xs a
      bs = xs \\ a
  in case (as, bs) of
    ((_ : _), (_ : _)) -> (as ++ bs) : findY xss a
    _                  -> findY xss a
findY _ _ = []
```

but in Haskell 2010, you can use pattern guards, a more powerful version of pattern matching. It makes your code that much clearer:

```
findY :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a] -> [[a]]
findY (xs : xss) a 
  | as@(_ : _) <- intersect xs a
  , bs@(_ : _) <- xs \\ a = (as ++ bs) : findY xss a
  | otherwise             = findY xss a
findY _ _ = []
```

Finally, the shape of your program is classic structural recursion. It is usually what you would use `foldr` for.

```
findY :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
findY a = foldr build []
  where 
    build xs yss
      | as@(_ : _) <- intersect xs a
      , bs@(_ : _) <- xs \\ a = (as ++ bs) : yss
      | otherwise             = yss
```